# BIRT reports: display text null when using multiplechoice

Tags: parameters, birt, multiple-choice

I want to display selected parameters inside of the report page, after the parameters are selected.

I had several listboxes and used different displayTexts and values.
After some development, I needed to change listboxes to use multiplechoice.

However after this change, displayTest is suddenly null.
I've explored and found that many people have encountered this issue, it's even a registered bug.

But I guess there must be a workaround using the scripts - maybe building the displayText string using some loop?

Has anybody solved this issue? Can you please provide me a working example?